# Do I have to port forward for local FTP server?

Tags: ftp

I have an FTP server set up, but only I can access it. Is it really necessary to port forward if I only want people connected to the same network to access it?

Comment: Just guessing: Firewall may be also involved in your problem. Unfortunately, you provided too little information to diagnose it remotely.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No. Port forwarding is only needed if you're exposing services to the public.

Comment: For some value of "public".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit anything outside your LAN could be considered public

Comment: Right, and there's nothing stopping you from having firewalls and/or multiple subnets set up inside your LAN, requiring port forwarding. Indeed, individual PCs often have firewalls enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to do anything on the router.

Port forwarding is (in typical/home networks) only required where you are running a server on an IP address which is not directly accessible - as is the case when your ISP provides you a single valid IP address and a number of computers share it.

(@td512 answer, while it encapsulates the just of the problem and is more-or-less correct, it is slightly off in as much as its got less to do with whether services are exposed to the public, and more to do with dealing with a 1:many relationship between IP addresses, or reaching an IP address which is not routed on the Internet)